# How can I replace all matches of a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace

I am trying to replace some sort of self made variables from multiple strings in an array.
Later I will make a promp for the user to ask for the replacement, but in the first step I'm just trying to replace it with a 'test' value ('###').
Oh and I want it to be simplified (with the chained functions - I've only just discovered for myself and thats the problem here :D ). Can someone please help me?

What I got so far:

```
const replaceAll = (obj) => {
    obj.cmds.forEach((element, index, array) => {
        obj.cmds[index] = obj.cmds[index].match(/{.*?}/gmi).map((value) => {
            console.log('valuex', value)
            /*
            // Here the user should be asked for the replacement in the future.
            // const newValue = userPromp(value)
            */
            return obj.cmds[index].split(value).join('###')
        })
    })

    return obj
}

const newObj = replaceAll({
    name: 'ULTRA TEST',
    cmds: [
        'port {port}',
        'port {port} und random {random}',
        'random {random} und value {value}'
    ]
})

console.log(newObj)
```

Comment: What are your current results?  I noticed when running it locally that you use map but you never assign it.   Could you try:   `obj.cmds[index] = obj.cmds[index].match(......`

Comment: MM. that doesnt return the right answer either.  Let me think it over.

Comment: Oh I saw that I forgot the part. I have i local like this: `obj.cmds[index] = obj.cmds[index].match(......`. But I only get an array in an array as an return. :'D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is something like this:
You can see that instead of using match, i just use Replace and pass in the regex.

```
replaceAll = (obj) => {
    var m = {};
    obj.cmds.forEach((element, index, array) => {
        obj.cmds[index].match(/{.*?}/gmi).map( value => {
          var r = m[value]
          if (!r) { /* Create Prompt here. */ r = Math.random() * 10 }
          m[value] = r;
        })
        Object.keys(m).map( key => {
          obj.cmds[index] = obj.cmds[index].replace(key, m[key])
        });
    })

    return obj
}
newObj = replaceAll({
    name: 'ULTRA TEST',
    cmds: [
        'port {port}',
        'port {port} und random {random}',
        'random {random} und value {value}'
    ]
})
```

The json which is returned by newObj is:

```
{
  "name":"ULTRA TEST",
  "cmds":[
    "port 1",
    "port 1 und random 2",
    "random 2 und value 3"
  ]
}
```

So what will happen is that it will only prompt the user for values not previously prompted for in that iteration of replaceAll.

This will do exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks for that. :) But I also want to display the user every single `{.*?}` and want to ask him for the exact replacement of each. Thats why I focused on the `map` function so much. ^^

Comment: To be more precise, I would like to replace each different `{.*?}` match with a different user input.

Comment: @borsTiHD take a look at my edit. Created it to your specifications. FOR a proof of concept, It is using a randomized Number to denote unique user entries.  That way you can see it is not just dumping ### but creating a mechanism to update values based on the unique matches.

Comment: Oh thats perfect. :D Exactly what I wanted to achive. Thank you so much.

Comment: @borsTiHD No problem!

Answer (score 1):

i guess you need something like this

```js
const replaceAll = obj => ({
  ...obj,
  cmds: obj.cmds.map(string => {
    let result = string;
    string.match(/{.*?}/gmi).forEach(template => { 
      // build <replace-string> here
      result = result.split(template).join('$$$'); 
    });
    return result; 
  })
}); 

const newObj = replaceAll({
    name: 'ULTRA TEST',
    cmds: [
        'port {port}',
        'port {port} und random {random}',
        'random {random} und value {value}'
    ]
})

console.log(newObj)
```

Comment: Oh, thats what I was original looking for (still prefere Fallenreapers answer, because the promp is not asking twicte for the same "template" variable). But I have a question. What exactly is the line 2 `...obj,` and line 3 `cmds: ` doing? Is this for a obj copy and reassign?

Comment: it is a way to copy an object. `{ ...obj }` copies all the properties of the `obj`, however i'm specifying `cmds` property by myself as it differs from the source one

Comment: Oh thats nice, because I encountered the following problem... I "replaced" my original obj I created as a source list. I'm using this list more than one time and after one "replace" all of my self made `{.*?}` were gone. Meanwhile I found a solution with JSON encode/decode for a deep copy of my original object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inbuilt replace function.
`String.replace(/regex here/, <string to replace the matched regex>)`

So for your case, I could do:

```
// take input here
let input = <input from user>

// string to replace with
let replacementString = "###"

for (let cmd of cmds) {
  cmd.replace(/`${input}`/gmi, replacementString);
}
```

Use `for of` instead of `forEach` as you cannot execute **break** in the latter. (Assuming you might want to have functionality of replacing one by one in the future).

Comment: Thanks for your help. The user input is optional for me right now. Still dont have a promp ready. But I want to replace all of `{.*?}` strings in the hole array (with different user inputs in the future). :)